# Magento Marketplace: After update the magento marketplace, extension stuck in "Awaiting Marketing Review"

Tags: extensions, marketplace

After updated the magento marketplace on 01 Oct 2018, it changed the look and feel of marketplace and there functionality. It also give the option to set scheduled to launch date and changed the launch date.

Unfortunately I am not able to change the launch date.
Also extension stuck in "Awaiting Marketing Review" status for very long time.

Please suggest what action should I take in this situation.

Comment: We had a similar issue with one of our extensions. We sent an email to marketplace@magento.com and they responded fast and were very helpful.

Comment: We find many issue after upgrade the marketplace on 2 Oct 2018